# MS CRM 2013 Dialog Process - Limit result of query crm data

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

**Summary:**

Is it possible to limit the number of results in an query crm step in a dialog process?

**Details:**

We have a lead workflow where every user should visit about 10 leads per day.
So I try to build a workflow which creates a list or appointments with 10 leads, not ready yet.

I created a dialog process which asks for a zipcode and then I want to query the leads and find them based on the input zipcode. That's working already. But my question is how can I limit the number of results in this query?

I found that I can use the "**count**" or "**top**" attribute in the fetchxml to limit the results. But how can I get this in the query in the dialog process?
In the creating-dialog-window you can only change the variables but not the query shown above that itself.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have in mind is following:

1. Create a solution and put your dialog inside.
2. Export solution from CRM and unarchive it to some folder.
3. Open Customizations.xml file with text editor and find FetchXml query that's used in your dialog.
4. Fix it using count directive like in fetch below.
5. Save file and pack it back to solution archive.
6. Try to import solution to CRM.

fetch mapping="logical" **count="10"** version="1.0"

Comment: But remember that this approach is unsupported so be carefull and backup your original solution before.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes just read something like that, looks like it would be a solution.

But I think I missunerstood the dialog and the query crm function in crm. Thought you could get a list of leads and put them in a marketing list or something like that.

Comment: Nope. As far as I know that only could be used for selecting of data to lookup variable at the dialog.